# Prove or disprove the existence of polynomials.

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove or disprove that there exist non-constant polynomials $p$ and $q$ such that $p(z)e^{p(z)}+q(z)e^{q(z)}=1$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. Take derivatives of both sides and group exponential and polynomial terms. What can you conclude?

Comment: Yes i have done this procedure and i was finding information about the common zeros and orders of zeros for f' and g' and f,g. I have a solution like this for the exercise. My problem is that i find all the time questions of the same type and i think that there is o common approach using Mittag-Leffler and Weierstrass factorization theorem to solve all of them. Either way thank you for your help.

Comment: For example here are three similar (i think) questions: given $f_1 and f_2$ holomorphic prove that there exist $g_1 and g_2$ holomorphic such that $f_1g_1+f_2g_2=1$.

Comment: Prove that there exist holomorphic functions $f and g$ such that $e^f+e^g=1$ for $z$ in the unit circle.