# Prove or disprove the existence of polynomials $p$ and $q$ for which $pe^p+qe^q=1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove or disprove that there exist non-constant polynomials $p$ and $q$ such that $p(z)e^{p(z)}+q(z)e^{q(z)}=1$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$.  This question was first asked here [Prove or disprove the existence of polynomials.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883581/prove-or-disprove-the-existence-of-polynomials), and I tried following the hint but could not solve the problem.

Taking the derivative of both sides yields $e^pp'(p+1)+e^qq'(q+1)=0$, and since $e^p$ and $e^q$ are never zero, we can conclude that $p'(p+1)=0$ if and only if $q'(q+1)=0$. I could not see how to finish the problem using only this information, so I must be missing something else. Thank you.

Comment: I think that you are on the good way. A hint to continue: We have not only that $p^{\prime}(p+1)$ and $q^{\prime}(q+1)$ have the same distincts roots, but  such root have also the same multiplicity in $p^{\prime}(p+1)$ and $q^{\prime}(q+1)$.

Comment: If you don't insist on following the hint, we have a nice argument using Picard's theorem. Suppose $p(z)e^{p(z)} + q(z)e^{q(z)} \equiv 1$ with polynomials $p,q$ both not identically $0$. Then $p(z)e^{p(z)}$ has only finitely many zeros, hence $q(z)e^{q(z)}$ attains the value $1$ only finitely many times. Also, $q\cdot e^q$ has only finitely many zeros. Thus $q\cdot e^q$ is an entire function that attains two distinct values at most finitely many times, hence it is constant. It follows that $q$ is constant. It follows that $p$ is constant.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer That is much cleaner. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We cannot have $p=q$ else $2pe^p=1$ leading to $2p=e^{-p}$ which for nonconstant $p$ cannot hold. And neither can we have $p-q=k$ for a constant $k,$ otherwise from $pe^p+(p+k)e^{p+k}=1$ follows $p+(p+k)e^k=e^{-p},$ which again cannot hold for nonconstant $p.$

Now consider the relatin $e^pp'(p+1)+e^qq'(q+1)=0$ and let $r=q-p,$ and say $a=p'(1+p),\ b=q'(1+q).$ Then we arrive at 
$a+b e^r=0,$ which cannot hold since taking enough derivatives makes the first term zero but not the second, since the polynomial $r$ is not a constant as noted above.

[Note that $b$ is not $0$ otherwise either $q' \equiv 0$ or $q \equiv 1$ and $q$ is assumed nonconstant.]

Answer (score 0):

I will attempt an answer based on Kelenner's comment.  Taking repeated derivatives of the the equation $pe^p+qe^q=1$ yields that $p'(p+1)$ and $q'(q+1)$ have the same distinct roots each with the same multiplicity.  Hence $q'(q+1)=\lambda p'(p+1)$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.

Hence $p'(p+1)[e^p+\lambda e^q]=0$ for all $z$.  Since $p'(p+1)$ has only finitely many zeros, $e^p+\lambda e^q=0$ for all $z$ by the uniqueness principle.  Thus $p=q+\log (-\lambda)$ on some branch of the logarithm on which $log(-\lambda)$ is defined. Hence $p'=q'$, so we must have that $(q+1)=\lambda (p+1)$. But this implies $p$ is constant, which it cannot be. Thus no such nonconstant polynomials $p$ and $q$ exist.